# Express js and mongodb merge two documents based on name

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

Lets say i have two documents inside the collection *athletes* that look like this

```
_id: whatever
name: "Usain BOLT"
gender: "Male"
country: "JAM"
competition: Array
__v: 4
```

and

```
_id: different whatever
name: "Usain BOLT"
gender: "Male"
country: "JAM"
competition: Array (different values inside the array)
__v: 0
```

How would i merge these two documents into one?
This is what i currently have, but it doesn't work:

```
aggregate: function(req, res)
{
    athletesModel.aggregate(
    [{$unwind: '$competition'}, 
     {$group: {
                  _id: '$name', 
                  competition: {$push: '$competition'}
               }
     }
    ]);
    return res.redirect('../../');
},
```

EDIT:
What i was expecting is `Usain BOLT` merged into **one** document, with a combined `competition` array.

```
_id: first or second whatever
name: "Usain BOLT"
gender: "Male"
country: "JAM"
competition: Array (all values from first document and second document)
__v: 0
```

What i got when requesting `/athletes/aggregate` is a 302 and nothing happened in the database.

Comment: What doesn't work about that?  What output did you get, and what were you expecting?

Comment: @Joe i have edited what i was expecting and what i got